# nodejs sockets failing

Tags: node.js

I keep getting an error when I try to start my script. If I remove the line calling "check();" then it works fine.

The error: node: ../src/node_io_watcher.cc:160: static v8::Handle node::IOWatcher::Set(const v8::Arguments&): Assertion `!io->watcher_.active' failed.

I am using version 6 I believe.

The code that is failing is below

```
function check(){
  hosts.forEach(function(item) {
    var sock = new net.Socket();
    sock.setTimeout(7500);
    ports.forEach(function(item1) {
      sock.on('connect', function() {
          console.log(item[0]+':'+item1[1]+' is up.');
          sock.destroy();
          serverstatus[item[1]][item1[0]] = "online";
      }).on('error', function(e) {
          console.log(item[0]+':'+item1[1]+' is down: ' + e.message);
          serverstatus[item[1]][item1[0]] = "offline";
      }).on('timeout', function(e) {
          console.log(item[0]+':'+item1[1]+' is down: timeout');
          serverstatus[item[1]][item1[0]] = "timeout";
      }).connect(item1[1], item[0]);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: is this for socket.io? if so, why are you adding a timeout?

Comment: this is for the standard net.socket. And the timeout is because the servers it is checking sometimes lock up to the point it'll hold the connection. Plus, 7.5s is the time the CEO wanted before reporting as timed out.

Comment: I've solved it. I moved var sock = ... and sock.setTimeout(...) to after ports.forEach(...